# Perl regular expression for string and digits - match only last 6 digits

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract last 6 digits from name of file (which is date) and regex for me doesnt work.

The string is: `name_of_file0000000546210618.A001.6476871457`

I need to contains just this: `name_of_file210618.A001`

My regex is: `name_of_file\(\d{6}).A\d{3}` - doesn't work

I tried also: `name_of_file(\d{6}).A\d{3}` - doesn't work

**More details:**

We already used `name_of_file(\d{6}).A\d{3}` and it has been working for more than 3 years. The string in those cases is just `name_of_file210618.A001.6476871457` and the regex takes just this: `name_of_file210618.A001`. And that is exactly what I need in this case, I need to handle the digits before `210618`.

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: `\d{6}` matches only 6 digits, `\(` will match a literal open parenthesis. `.A\d{3}` matches 1 any character, a literal "A" followed by 3 digits. None of this matches what your string is. How did you think this would work?

Comment: Also, do you really have the exact string `name_of_file` in your regex? Presumably this regex is meant to match a lot of *different* strings. Is this part of your string set fixed? What do the other strings look like?

Comment: @TLP because we already use this and it works more than 3 years: name_of_file(\d{6}).A\d{3} and the string in those cases is just name_of_file210618.A001.6476871457 - and regex takes just this: name_of_file210618.A001 - and that is exact what i need in my case up, i need to handle the digits before 210618...

Comment: It's not obvious _at all_ from the question that `chardigits` actually mean "the character `A` followed by three digits". Please provide real examples.

Comment: @KláraJanstová Your sample string does not look like that at all. You need to update your question to clarify exactly what your strings look like. And preferably add a few test cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
name_of_file\K\d*(?=\d{6}\.A\d{3})
```

Replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qi3JvE/3). Details:

- `name_of_file` - a specific string
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `(?=\d{6}\.A\d{3})` - a positive lookahead that requires six digits, `.A` and three digits to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Perl demo online](https://ideone.com/L8nfyN):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;
 
my $str = "name_of_file0000000546210618.A001.6476871457";
say $str =~ s/name_of_file\K\d*(?=\d{6}\.A\d{3})//r;
```

Output:

```
name_of_file210618.A001.6476871457
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete all digits followed by 6 digits:

```
perl -pe 's/\d*(?=\d{6})//' <<< 'name_of_file0000000546210618.chardigits.digits'
```

Comment: Since the OP changed what the string looks like, this will no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your regex

```
name_of_file\(\d{6}).A\d{3}
#           ^^--- escaped parenthesis
```

Does not work is because it expects a literal parenthesis `(` in your string. Since there are none, this will never match.

This regex

```
name_of_file(\d{6}).A\d{3}
```

Will not match, since you have it "anchored" between `name_of_file` and `.A`, with no allowance for characters in between.

The simplest fix to allow extra filler numbers is to simply add `\d*` before your capture area. You should also escape `.` since it is a regex meta character that means "match any character except newline".

```
name_of_file\d*(\d{6})\.A\d{3}
```

This will now allow the regex to match more loosely with strings such as

```
name_of_file0000000546210618.A001.6476871457
#           ^^^^^^^^^^---- unneeded numbers
```

Similarly, you could just remove the anchor before the numbers

```
(\d{6})\.A\d{3}
```

It is strange to me to have the string `name_of_file` in a regex. If it is a placeholder for an actual file name, it would mean that you hard code a file name in your regex, meaning it will only match that exact filename, and nothing else. Usually, you want regexes to match a number of *different* type of strings. I would expect a regex to match different file names to look something like:

```
 [\pL_]+\d*(\d{6})\.A\d{3}
#^^^^^^-- matching letters and underscore
```

It seems like what you need to capture, however, is not the number, like your regex shows, but the filename also, in a string like this: `name_of_file210618.A001`. In that case, you would need to perform some more operations. It might be possible to execute with a substitution to remove unwanted characters, but it is much simpler to just use a regex and concatenation, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($name, $num) = /([\pL_]+)\d*(\d{6}.A\d{3})/;
    my $str = join '', $name, $num;
    print Dumper $str;
}

__DATA__
name_of_file210618.A001.6476871457
name_of_file0000000546210618.A001.6476871457
foo_of_bar210618.A001.6476871457
```

This will print

```
$VAR1 = 'name_of_file210618.A001';
$VAR1 = 'name_of_file210618.A001';
$VAR1 = 'foo_of_bar210618.A001';
```